# Creating a backdoor in (your own) PHP website

Tags: web-development, security

I've just built a website for a client and I'm a bit worried he won't pay me once it actually goes live.

I've heard there are ways to create a back-door so I could access the website whenever I want. Can anybody point to where I could learn to do this?

Answer (score 4):

Building back-doors into your client's system could lead to legal issues if discovered, as well as destroy your own reputation.

The better option would be to ensure payment is made before final delivery of a product. At the very least you could require a deposit to be paid up front and ensure your contract provides clear legal recourse in the event of non-payment.